# Style Inheritance with UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I am trying to customise the style of a usercontrol, inheriting its style and adding some additional styling to it. I made a small project to try this. Let's say I have a user control called `UserControl1` (what it contains is irrelevant - it's empty in my sample project).

I'm using it in my `MainWindow` as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfStyleInheritance.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfStyleInheritance"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl1>
            <local:UserControl1.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:UserControl1}" BasedOn="{x:Type local:UserControl1}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                </Style>
            </local:UserControl1.Style>
        </local:UserControl1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

On the `BasedOn` part, I'm getting the error:

> The specified value cannot be assigned. The following type was expected: "Style".

If I change it to `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type local:UserControl1}}"`, then I get the error:

> The resource "{x:Type local:UserControl1}" could not be resolved.

How can I get this working and live happily ever after?

**Edit**: as I posted in the comments of an answer here, if I go the StaticResource route and run, I get a XamlParseException with message:

> Cannot find resource named 'WpfStyleInheritance.UserControl1'. Resource names are case sensitive.

Additional info: if I replace all instances of `local:UserControl1` in MainWindow markup with `Button`, it works quite nicely. The problem is with user controls.

**Edit 2**: If I add a style in the UserControl, the problem remains:

```
<UserControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="UserControl">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`BasedOn`** syntax is incorrect. It should be:

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type local:UserControl1}}"
```

---

And even if you are getting designer error, try to re-compile your code. Make sure namespace added is correctly mapped to your UserControl.

Also, make sure *MainWindow* and *UserControl1* resides in same assembly.

If they resides in different assemblies, you have to specify assembly name in namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfStyleInheritance;assembly=AssemblyName"
```

---

**UPDATE**

In case you haven't defined any default style for **`UserControl1`**, you don't need to use **`BasedOn`** since no default Style for your UserControl exist. That's why you are getting an exception.

Remove the BasedOn and it will work fine.

---

Resource you have defined within XAML is not a default style but instead a local Style of UserControl which will be overridden in case you define another local resource in MainWindow.

If you want default style for your UserControl1, declare that under **`Application resources`** i.e. in **`App.xaml`**.

```
<Application.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:UserControl1}">
      <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
   </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

and now in MainWindow.xaml, this will work fine:

```
<local:UserControl1>
    <local:UserControl1.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:UserControl1}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type local:UserControl1}}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </local:UserControl1.Style>
</local:UserControl1>
```

Comment: I tried that, as I explained in the question. If I run, I get a XamlParseException

Comment: Can you post inner exception for XamlParseException?

Comment: Cannot find resource named 'WpfStyleInheritance.UserControl1'. Resource names are case sensitive.

Comment: Can you post code for UserControl1? Most likely assembly is different or name is not correct.

Comment: It's just an empty UserControl, the kind you get after Add New Item.

Comment: Oh, it's blank that means you haven't defined any default Style. So you have to omit BasedOn since no default style exist for that control.

Comment: See edits in my question - problem remains (I appreciate your answer though).